# Determining max number in C with recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I am a beginner and its not my idea to do it with recursion, its the assignment.

Comment: do you know the basics of `functions`?

Comment: The `scanf` should be in the function.

Comment: Well .. I am an absolute beginner.. Thts why I am looking for help.

Comment: Recursion with input? A sick idea...

Comment: Your recursion makes no sense. The max of a single value is the value itself.

Comment: The function should be recursive. If I am putting scanf inside of  function, how do I call it at main and make it execute the function?

Comment: That's the question, its on the topic of recursion. We have to use recursion.

Comment: call max_number with parameters and define it without one

Comment: Hint: Let the `max` function take as a parameter the currently known maximum.

Comment: `scanf` should absolutely not be in the function.  If you are a beginner, you should avoid scanf like the plague.  If you are an intermediate programmer (whatever that means) you should avoid scanf like the flu. If you are an expert, you should avoid scanf like a rabid dog.  Do not go down that rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you the pseudocode to not spoil the whole fun. The trick is to keep track of the currently found maximum and compare it to the given input.

```
function max(current_max)
    read number
    if number == 0 return current_max
    if number > current_max then current_max = number
    return max(current_max)
```

your constraints hint that `0` cannot be the result of your max function, so it is safe to pass it as initial value. So you can invoke

```
print max(0)
```

and watch the results...

Comment: Ohh thanks for the guidance. I had a problem with envisioning the input. But now I understand i can input number by number.

Answer (score 1):

It's shocking that abelenky's code does not check the return value from `scanf`. Here's the code with proper error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(void)
{
    int m, n;
    return ((m = scanf("%d", &n), m --> 0) && n) ? n > (m =max()) ? n : m : 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", max());
}
```

Comment: You didn't return a value in main.

Comment: Having fun, people?

Comment: @EugeneSh. that really tired me, you right I'm done for today

Comment: thank you. Now I can go to sleep happy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(void)
{
    int n,m;

    printf("Enter a number (0 to end):\n");
    scanf("%d", &n );
    return !n?n:n>(m=max())?n:m;
}

int main(void) {
    return !printf("The Maximum number is %d\n", max() );
}
```

**Output**

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4444KB
Enter a number (0 to end): 4
Enter a number (0 to end): 3
Enter a number (0 to end): 5
Enter a number (0 to end): 6
Enter a number (0 to end): 1
Enter a number (0 to end): 2
Enter a number (0 to end): 0
The Maximum number is 6
```

Comment: P.S. Do not try to turn in this code to your instructor.  It is valid, but uses multiple non-standard techniques.   You can still learn from it.

Comment: How should I input the series of numbers, with spaces, commas, or without? Without them its just returning me the number ive entered itself

Comment: Ohhh.. I got it.. You are entering one by one.

Comment: `!n?n:n>(m=max())?n:m;` nice. If you throw the "goes to" operator (`-->`) in there you get a +1 from me.

Comment: i don't think that a no tail recursion should be learn to someone who learn recursion.

Comment: @stargateur I am sorry to say you clearly don't get the point of this post

Comment: I reject your edit, @Stargateur

Comment: @abelenky well it's your answer, sorry about that ;) bolov if you say so it must be true. ugly code must be a good solution if you say it.

Comment: @Stargateur:  This is NOT a good solution.  I don't want to give him the solution to his homework.  It is however, a correct solution that he can perhaps get ideas from.

Comment: Well, sorry to consider a bad solution as a bad answer ;)

Comment: @bolov I put in a "goes to" operator in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930137/3386109) just for you :)

Comment: This is a great answer, which will certainly make the OP do some research and learn some things.  I would however strongly recommend removing the `printf` from the `max` function, as that is a poor practice that ought not be demonstrated.  Tools like this are generally used as filters, and prompting for input breaks that model.  Imagine if `grep` printed `enter the next line of input to scan` before reading each line of input!

Comment: In the edit history of the question, it was originally specified that the function should do the `printf`/`scanf`, and return when the input was 0.  I agree that this is not good design, but it was what was specified.